# jplayer no funciona en safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

me e descargado el jplayer v2.9.2 con JQuery v1.11.1 el cual ha funcionado correctamente en todos los navegadores, menos en safari, he navegado para encontrar una solución pero no me funciona, este es código que estoy usando.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

new jPlayerPlaylist({
    jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
    cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
}, [        
    {
        title:"Partir",
        mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-09-Partir.mp3",
        oga:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-09-Partir.ogg"
    },
    {
        title:"Thin Ice",
        mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-10-Thin-ice.mp3",
        oga:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-10-Thin-ice.ogg"
    },
    {
        title:"Thin Ice",
        mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-10-Thin-ice.mp3",
        oga:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-10-Thin-ice.ogg"
    },
    {
        title:"Thin Ice",
        mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-10-Thin-ice.mp3",
        oga:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-10-Thin-ice.ogg"
    }       
], {
    swfPath: "/jplayer",
    solution: "html,flash"
    supplied: "oga, mp3",
    wmode: "window",
    useStateClassSkin: true,
    autoBlur: false,
    smoothPlayBar: true,
    keyEnabled: true
});
});
```

los ejemplos descargados de la misma pagina de jplayer no funcionan al menos el de la playlist, agradezco la ayuda.

Comment: de da algún error (consola) en safari?

Comment: gracias por responder @aldanux, en la consola no muestra nada :(

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque es acerca de un problema que ya no puede ser reproducido o que se debió a un simple error tipográfico.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He encontrado la solución, la dejo por acá para alguien mas que la necesite, el problema es la ruta del swf, lo tenia así

```
swfPath: "/jplayer"
```

al ponerle el / no ubica el swf, hay que removerle el primer /, eso es todo, gracias (jplayer es la carpeta donde se encuentra el swf).

```
swfPath: "jplayer",
```